# Submitting a form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

The form on the page is generated in a standard way:

```cs
<%using (Html.BeginForm("<method>", "<controller>", FormMethod.Post))
```

There is a table on the form, as well as a button to delete each row with an indication of the handler:

```js
onclick="deleteElem(this)"
```

The handler of this button:

```js
$("#delete").live('click', function (event) {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Deleting a line works correctly. But after deleting at least 1 row in the table, the form submission button simply reloads the page and the ViewData turns out to be empty. How can this be explained?
Is it impossible to delete the data on the page and then submit the form? Is it necessary to implement the removal of each element through a controller method call?

UPD:
See freedomn-m's comment, this is the solution.

Comment: You may need to unregister the event associated with the button before removing the row.

Comment: @jdweng, I.e. delete the listener? After deleting, re-assign it?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events?force_isolation=true#unsubscribing

Comment: Consider a "soft-delete". Instead of removing the elements from the DOM, add a hidden field / property on your model for "IsRemoved" and set this via the js along with *hiding* the row (.hide(), not .remove()).  Then check for IsRemoved in your back-end.   Posting (form submission) of lists does funny things when you remove part of the list - the whole list must be sequential and soft-delete is *much* easier than trying to resequence.

Comment: @freedomn-m, how can I mark an item for deletion? Via hidden?

Comment: > add a hidden field / property on your model for "IsRemoved" and set this via the js along with hiding the row

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes, I have already done it. Thanks!

Comment: @freedomn-m, I would like to know what causes the strict sequence for lists. Except for the answer "because it happened that way" =)

Comment: The ModelMapper sits between the POST values and the controller action parameters.  Your POST values become `val[0]` `val[2]` (when [1] is deleted).  As these are not in sequence, it fails.

Comment: Here's the original article (from 2008) : https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/